# Angular 9 `*ngFor` not working with `Array` of object

Tags: angular, angular-ngfor

In ts file I have a data like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
 this.images = [{
     asset_id: 'asset_id',
     asset_name: 'asset_name'
 }];
```

and html template is as below:

**app.component.html**

```html
test {{images}}
<div *ngFor="let img of images; index as i">
  dddd--<span>{{img.asset_id}}</span>
</div>
```

The result is like the below:

[image]

**What is the mistake I am doing here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `array` of `object` with one item. So, try this:

```html
id: {{images[0]["asset_id"]}}
name: {{images[0]["asset_name"]}}

<div *ngFor="let img of images">
    <span>{{ img.asset_id  }}</span>
</div>
```

I created a sample for you here on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wcerf9?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `test [object Object]` is bcz you are trying to print array without iteration.

To print array of object without iteration we need to either use index to access array value or use `json` pipe to print object or array of object.

```
// output: test [ { "asset_id": "asset_id", "asset_name": "asset_name" } ]
test {{ images | json }}
```

Or access using array index

```
{{ images[0].asset_id }}
{{ images[0].asset_name }}
...
```